# XNA How does the ContentManager handle with memory

Tags: xna, content-management

My question is not clear at title [i can not write it exactly]

e.g `Texture2D picture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("myPicture");`

what does happen on memory if the code above runs ? As I know Content caches the "myPicture" to the memory and return a reference to the Texture2D picture. Am I wrong ? If "myPicture" is loaded to another Texture2D object "myPicture" is not duplicated so it returns only a reference.

Is each file (or content-file) loaded over Content cached to memory (also allocated on Ram) without duplicating ? (i believe this my question with all written above should be checked)

Thanks !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each instance of `ContentManager` will only load any given resource once. The second time you ask for a resource, it will return the *same* instance that it returned last time.

```
ReferenceEquals(Content.Load<Texture2D>("something"),
                Content.Load<Texture2D>("something")) == true
```

To do this, `ContentManager` maintains a list of all the content it has loaded internally. This list prevents the garbage collector from cleaning up those resources - even if you are not using them.

To unload the resources and clear that internal list, call `ContentManager.Unload`. This will free up the memory the loaded resources were using. Now if you ask for the same resource again - it will be re-loaded.

Of course, if you *are* using those resources when you call `Unload`, all of those shared instances that you loaded will be disposed and unusable.

Finally, don't call `Dispose` on anything that comes out of `ContentManager.Load`, as this will break all the instances that are being shared and cause problems when `ContentManager` tries to dispose of them in `Unload` later on.

Comment: Thanks for the post ! Morely the loaded resource are hold at memory, right ? (your sentence about unload make it clear for me, but i ask it a second time, my english is not well enough to understand completely.)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: Texture2D picture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("myPicture"); after running this line, myPicture is loaded to the memory (to computer's ram) and its reference is return by Content to Texture2D instance picture. -> true or false ? Thanks !