# Doesn't Content.Load<Texture2D>() create a new instance?

Tags: c#, reference, xna, xna-4.0

I have this struct:

```
public struct LevelElements
{
    public Texture2D levelTexture;
    // other variables...
}
```

and I initialize it in this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    levelElements[i] = new LevelElements
    {
        levelTexture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Terrain/level"),
        // other variables...
    }
```

Then I draw the first texture while modifying it with `textureLevel.SetData` method.
The problem is that if I draw the second one it looks the same as the modified first one, and not as the original one loaded from the content.
Why have both `levelTexture`s the same reference? Doesn't `Content.Load<Texture2D>()` create a new instance?

PS: I don't need to create a copy of that texture, I was only testing my code and I found this behaviour.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870420/165500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it before but it seems to me that you would want to declare it like this in order to use it as an instance variable:

`Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(
                          resourceDevice, 
                          image.PixelWidth, 
                          image.PixelHeight,
                          false, 
                          SurfaceFormat.Color);`

[read on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712857%28v=vs.95%29.aspx): from msdn

Comment: Nice method, but BitmapSourceExtensions.CopyTo seems to exists only in Silverlight. Anyway your solution is correct, "forcing" the creation of a new instance it now works!

Comment: yea I wasn't suggesting that you use that exact method, just that you need to instantiate a "new" instance of Texture2D instead of using the static declaration.