# Does using a static Texture2D with SpriteBatch improve performance?

Tags: c#, static, xna, textures, spritebatch

I am going to have lots of (same looking) zombies in my game.

Is it a good idea to make the texture static, so that `SpriteBatch` wont need to load a new texture?

I go through the whole zombie list and draw every zombie with the same call, just changing the position. Will `SpriteBatch` get it? That its exactly the same texture every time? Where could be the disadvantage?

Comment: If you're using the same texture object, the sprite batch will notice it. If it's another object, it will not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the use of `static` will give you some kind of benefit.
What's sure is that, if you load your `Texture2D` only once, you save memory and you can draw it how many times you need using the same variable.

Anyway, if you're using only one texture you don't have any problem, because:

> Each instance of ContentManager will only load any given resource
> once. The second time you ask for a resource, it will return the same
> instance that it returned last time.
>
> ContentManager maintains a list of all the content it has loaded
> internally. This list prevents the garbage collector from cleaning up
> those resources.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9870420/2498113).