# Properly end SoundEffectInstance

Tags: c#, .net, audio, xna, xna-4.0

What I want to do is to `Load()` a sound effect in XNA using the Content Manager and automatically create a instance to control playback. When the sound is no longer needed, I was wondering how to properly `Unload()` it from memory?

Furthermore, I was wondering if `Unload()` is even needed. When I call `Load()` twice, does the second call properly free the memory of the first call? I would guess that the C# garbage collector automatically disposes the old effect and instance as they are being overwritten by the second call. Is this correct?

These are the parameters in my custom `MySoundEffect` class:

```
// Has sound effect been loaded?
bool loaded;

// Store our SoundEffect resource
SoundEffect effect;

// Instance of our SoundEffect to control playback
SoundEffectInstance instance;
```

This method is loading the sound.

```
public void Load(String location)
{
    effect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>(location);

    if (effect != null) loaded = true;
    else
    {
        Error.Happened("Loading of sound effect " + location + " failed.");
        return;
    }

    // Create instance
    instance = effect.CreateInstance();
}
```

This is called when the sound is no longer needed:

```
public void Unload()
{
    loaded = false;

    instance.Dispose();

    effect.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unload a single sound you can call `Dispose` method, but it's important that you never need it again, or you'll receive an excepion of disposed element.
You can create a second `ContentManager` where you can load the sounds that you use only one time, and then `Unload` it.

To answer to your second question, you are wrong:

> Each instance of ContentManager will only load any given resource
>   once. The second time you ask for a resource, it will return the same
>   instance that it returned last time.
>
> To do this, ContentManager maintains a list of all the content it has
>   loaded internally. This list prevents the garbage collector from
>   cleaning up those resources - even if you are not using them.

Comment: So when I overwrite all references to a asset loaded using the ContentManager, it is still not disposed by the Garbage Collector? Wouldn't this undermine the sense of a GC completely?

Comment: I think you need to manually unload them calling Content.Unload().

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911006/garbage-collector-behaviour/19911036?noredirect=1#19911036) contradicts that?

Comment: I referenced [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870420/2498113) answer. I trust a user that has 19k rep points.

Comment: If you look at that question again you'll see that the answer is changed, as I told you.